# Call Node 'require' function from within browser JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

On [one page](https://www.familyhistoryconferencenwa.org/class-schedule-2019) of a Squarespace [website](https://www.familyhistoryconferencenwa.org/), I need to call the Node js 'require' function from within the page JavaScript. I'm working locally with a min-test case. Node is installed.

The relevant code is:

```
require('dotenv').config();
AWS.config.update({
  'region': process.env.AWS_REGION,
  'accessKeyId' : process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  'secretAccessKey' : process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  'endpoint' : process.env.ENDPOINT
});
```

The 'secret' ID and Key values will be stored in a hidden environment variable, .env, not on the page.

With this code alone, I get a require-undefined error. I need the necessary code to get the Node function recognized in JavaScript.

I've seen questions on here going the other way, getting a JavaScript function recognized in Node, but none this way. In those answers, I didn't see anything I can use. I searched the net too, but most of the responses were questions on here.

Comment: After the problem that you don't have `require` in the browser, you'll have the problem that you don't have access to `process.env` either. That code is running in your user's browsers, you can't keep secrets from them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You imply that there is no way I can, at least to some degree, 'hide' `.env`. I have access to site:js. Couldn't I bury it in there? It would still be on the page but not easily discoverable.  You suggest that 'require' is available. I get an undefined error. Isn't 'process' also a Node function? Can I put Node on the page just as I have the AWS-SDK and jQuery? (How does one make paragraphs in comments?)

Comment: Security by obscurity isn't really security at all. Always assume the front-end is compromised

Comment: You need to move this code to the back-end.  Make an Ajax call from the front-end to the back-end and have the back-end execute whatever secure access to AWS  you need.  The client can NEVER be given secrets.  There is no way to protect them in the front-end.  Where were you ever getting the idea that this code should execute in the front-end.  I'm quite sure that SquareSpace's developer docs never told you to do this.  So, wherever you got this idea from, you must have misunderstood what you are supposed to be doing.

Comment: And, there is no version of the nodejs `require()` that runs in the browser.  That is a nodejs function that runs only on your server.  Also, you don't run nodejs functions in the browser - ever.  You run them in your nodejs server.  If the client code needs something that runs only on the server, you either embed that information in the original web page when the page is requested (dynamic content) or you make an ajax call from the web page to your server to ask the server to do some operation or to retrieve some result.

Comment: @jfriend00 Even using the Squarespace Developer Platform, I have no access whatsoever to the sever-side. The Squarespace documentation makes that all too clear, unfortunately. Client-side is all I can control. Do you mean to say that, in that case, I have can have no access at all to Node js? AWS wants me not to include the actual ID and Key values in `AWS.Config.Update()`.  If I have no Node js access on the front-end, some obscurity is perhaps the best 'security' I have.

Comment: You cannot use nodejs features in a browser.  The nodejs environment does not run in a browser.  There is, of course, Javascript code that runs in a browser, but you can't use nodejs features in a browser.  What is the connection in your code between your use of AWS and SquareSpace?  The AWS stuff you're trying to do there is meant for a nodejs server, not for a browser.

Comment: @jfriend00 I store data on DynamoDB that I use to build a table dynamically on the page before it's displayed. It was the solution I devised before I understood the server-side/client-side distinction. Squarespace allows code injection into the `<head>.` tag.  On the Squarespace Developer Platform, I have access to site:js, inter alia, which is seeming to be the only place I can "bury" the code that creates `.env.`

Comment: Nothing in the client is secure.  So, if you're changing a database directly from the client, then ANY hacker in the world will have full access to your DynamoDB (that's really bad).  You really need your own nodejs server that controls access to the DynamicDB (including all your credentials) and you send Ajax calls from the browser to your nodejs server which then securely talks to your DynamicDB database.  Your nodejs server can then validate incoming requests to see if they are reasonable and you keep all your AWS credentials only on your nodejs server.

Comment: As you say, this is about fully understanding the distinction between client and server and what is appropriate to do where.  It sounds like your trying to extend SquareSpace to do more than it was designed to do.  For that, you really need your own nodejs server that the code you inject into the client can talk to.

Comment: @jfriend00 So, it appears that it's time to migrate the site from Squarespace to somewhere else. Have you any suggestions? Three or so alternatives that I can evaluate if you are uncomfortable recommending a specific one. And, thanks for all the help.

Comment: That's not my specialty or experience to recommend a specific tool like that.  It also would take a far greater understanding of what your needs are and it's generally considered off-topic here to get into recommending specific 3rd party products.  Sorry, I'm not more help on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll summarize several relevant points from my comments:

1. First off here, it's very important to understand the distinction between running code in a browser and running code in your own nodejs server and what types of activities are appropriate for each.
2. You can't run nodejs code in a browser.  While both the browser and nodejs can run vanilla Javascript code, the entire nodejs run-time library is only available within the nodejs environment, not in the browser.   Similarly, there are many things such as the DOM that are available within the browser environment.  So, something like `require()` and the `dotenv` module are entirely designed to be run in a nodejs environment (typically a server), not in a browser.  There are some third party modules that can be run in either environment (such as Axios for making http requests from other servers).
3. Nothing that you embed into client-side Javascript in a browser is secure.  It is all available to any hacker or developer. So, you would never want to put AWS credentials into a web page.
4. When using credentials (such as your AWS credentials) or accessing a database (such as your DynamoDB), you will not want to access those directly from the browser.  To do so, you will have embed your credentials right into the web page and that will give any hacker full access to your database where they can wreak all sorts of havoc.
5. Instead, you will need to set up your own server that manages your AWS credentials and controls what is and isn't modified in the database.  Doing it this way, you keep your credentials secure on your server (never put them in the client) and your nodejs server has the ability to decide what changes to the database are appropriate and what are not.
6. Then, if you want to make some changes to the database from the client (add, modify, delete), you send an Ajax call from the browser web page to your nodejs server specifying what you want to change.  Your nodejs server validates the request (makes sure it's a reasonable thing to do, checks if the user making the request has the rights to do so) and then your nodejs server can login to the database using your AWS credentials and make the appropriate change to the database.
7. If the client wants a result back, then your server can send back the appropriate result.

Comment: I would only add that it's now obvious that I need to migrate the site to somewhere else. That's the bottom-line solution.